# fast hex to binary conversion method in .net

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I am developing an application in C#.net. I have to do a quick hex to binary conversion. What I have done is...

```
rtpPTypeNum = string.Join(string.Empty, udp.Payload.ToHexadecimalString().Substring(2, 2).Select(C => Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(C.ToString(), 16), 2).PadLeft(4, '0'))).Substring(1, 7);
```

I have checked its performance, but this is not good enough for me.

`udp.Payload.ToHexadecimalString()` returns a string of hex digits.

In this conversion I have to do around 9000 iterations.

Can you give me a better method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The top result on Google gives me:

```
return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you are expecting your number to be long 
        Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(hexstring, 16), 2);